# Java - Construct a signed numeric String and convert it to an integer

Tags: java, string, integer, sign

Can I somehow prepend a minus sign to a numeric String and convert it into an int?
In example:

If I have 2 Strings :

```
String x="-";
String y="2";
```

how can i get them converted to an Int which value is -2?

Comment: What value are you expecting?

Comment: Unclear asking. See "minus is an operator", converting an operator into number is meaning less.

Comment: how a "-" can be converted to an integer?

Comment: You'll get `NumberFormatException` in this case. What else can you expect?

Comment: Well...no.  You can't.  Because `-` isn't a number.  Could you clarify why you want to do this?  Are you trying to negate a number?

Comment: Is there any way to make it consider it as a minus?

Comment: That doesn't make sense; what *value* would you expect `result` to have?

Comment: Slow down guys.  Perhaps the OP is trying to negate a number and is going about it an incorrect way.  Let's get some clarification from them before we jump down their throat about the pure syntax.

Comment: @Makoto: Sure, but the OP needs to better explain what they're after, then...

Comment: Can you provide a use-case?

Comment: I have 2 Strings one as "-" the other as "2", i have to get it like integer -2.

Comment: Okay.  That's answerable.  In several ways.  Although it's strange that you'd have two strings like that.

Comment: 0 ,1 ,-1  this are an integer , whereas -,+,*,/ comes under operator if they are alone.

Comment: @Mr.Sarunov: Ok, you should edit your question to explain *that*.

Comment: `I have 2 Strings one as "-" the other as "2", i have to get it like integer -2` @Mr.Sarunov elaborate on *this* in your question. :)

Comment: I have a very simple answer... Just waiting for the question to be reopened.

Comment: @DerGolem how can I reopen it?

Comment: YOU **can't**. We have to wait for a fifth person who wants to reopen the question. It takes 5 "OTHER" persons to vote for reopening the question. Anyway... being so short, I can put my answer in this comment: `int value = Integer.parseInt(x + y);`

Comment: I really can't figure out why the others don't see the solution, which is pretty clear (at least, to my very simple mind)...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: He only wants to concatenate the two strings and convert the resulting string to an int.

Comment: @DerGolem Cheers mate, appreciate that :)

Comment: @Mr.Sarunov: I hope it was helpful. ;)

Comment: @DerGolem of course while I was waiting for the answer I took a longer way to do my exercise. But now I will just simplify it.  Anyway cheers :)

Comment: @Mr.Sarunov: I reworded your title and question to make it more evident. Now there should really be no doubts on what is your intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first have to concatenate both `Strings` since `-` is not a valid integer character an sich. It is however acceptable when it's used together with an integer value to denote a negative value.

Therefore this will print `-2` the way you want it:

```
String x = "-";
String y = "2";
int i = Integer.parseInt(x + y);
System.out.println(i);
```

Note that the `x + y` is used to concatenate 2 `Strings` and not an arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.valueOf("-")` will throw a `NumberFormatException` because `"-"` by itself isn't a number. If you did `"-1"`, however, you would receive the expected value of -1.

If you're trying to get a character code, use the following:

```
(int) "-".charAt(0);
```

[`charAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) returns a `char` value at a specific index, which is a two-byte unicode value that is, for all intensive purposes, an integer.

Comment: This doesn't seem like what was being asked.

Comment: @Makoto I added a comment about `"-"` not being an integer. I provided an alternative if it was what he was looking for.

Comment: @Mr.Sarunov `int=2;` isn't valid java. What are you trying to do? Can you add more detail to your question?